# DRF filters.SearchFilter don'e work when I modify the get method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this vide and it was working just find

```
class UsersView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UsersSerializer
    search_fields = ('username', 'email')
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
```

but when I changed it to

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context = {'request': request, 'method': 'view'}
        items = queryset_filtering(self.queryset.model, request.GET)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            items, context=context, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

the `/users/?search=Alex` don't work anymore?

Comment: How did you implement `queryset_filtering`? Normally that is done through `filter_backends`.

Comment: oh that is just a function, have this name don't care about it

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]`

Also, why have you overridden the get method? for adding additional context?

to add additional context in serializer, you can use this method:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'view': self
        }
```

Please remove your get method as you override it without any purpose,

to add additional context in serializers, just try with this

Try this:

```
class UsersView(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UsersSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ('username', 'email')

    def get_serializer_context(self):
       """
       Extra context provided to the serializer class.
       """
       return {
            'request': self.request,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'view': self
        }
```

Comment: I tried this did not worke Still the same problem

Comment: Please check again my answer